# issue in creating Backspace key behaviour in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

```
public partial class Backspace : Window
{
    Control TextBoxDetails;
    TextBox BehaveTextbox;
    public Backspace()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        // Insert code required on object creation below this point.
    }

    private void btn_t_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        BehaveTextbox = TextBoxDetails as TextBox;
        if (TextBoxDetails != null)
        {
            var _CareIndex = BehaveTextbox.CaretIndex;
            BehaveTextbox.Text = BehaveTextbox.Text.Insert(_CareIndex, "      ");
            BehaveTextbox.Focus();
            BehaveTextbox.CaretIndex = _CareIndex + 6;
        }
    }

    private void btn_s_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        BehaveTextbox = TextBoxDetails as TextBox;
        if (TextBoxDetails != null)
        {
            var _CareIndex = BehaveTextbox.CaretIndex;
            BehaveTextbox.Text = BehaveTextbox.Text.Insert(_CareIndex, " ");
            BehaveTextbox.Focus();
            BehaveTextbox.CaretIndex = _CareIndex + 1;
        }
    }

    private void btn_bs_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        BehaveTextbox = TextBoxDetails as TextBox;

        if (TextBoxDetails != null)
        {

            string _CurrentValue = BehaveTextbox.Text;
            var _CareIndex = BehaveTextbox.CaretIndex;

            if (_CareIndex > 0)
            {
                string _Backspace = _CurrentValue.Remove(_CareIndex - 1, 1);
                BehaveTextbox.Text = _Backspace;
                BehaveTextbox.Focus();
                BehaveTextbox.CaretIndex = _CareIndex - 1;
            }
        }
    }

    private void txt_result_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBoxDetails = (Control)sender;
    }
}
```

[image: Design]

in above figure textbox has some text value.I put 3 spaces between **111** and **222** by clicking SPACE button(btn_s)3 time,Then put 2 tab between **222** and **333** by clicking TAB button(btn_t) 2 time.

When I click the Backspace button(btn_bs), each time only one space or letter will clear.But what i want to do is, when click Backspace button(btn_bs), if there is tabed in text box, That should remove. If there is spaced in textbox, That would  remove.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        Control TextBoxDetails;
        TextBox BehaveTextbox;

        private void btn_t_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            BehaveTextbox = TextBoxDetails as TextBox;
            if (TextBoxDetails != null)
            {
                var _CareIndex = BehaveTextbox.CaretIndex;
                BehaveTextbox.Text = BehaveTextbox.Text.Insert(_CareIndex, "\t");
                BehaveTextbox.Focus();
                BehaveTextbox.CaretIndex = _CareIndex + 1;
            }
        }

        private void btn_s_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            BehaveTextbox = TextBoxDetails as TextBox;
            if (TextBoxDetails != null)
            {
                var _CareIndex = BehaveTextbox.CaretIndex;
                BehaveTextbox.Text = BehaveTextbox.Text.Insert(_CareIndex, " ");
                BehaveTextbox.Focus();
                BehaveTextbox.CaretIndex = _CareIndex + 1;
            }
        }

        private void btn_bs_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            BehaveTextbox = TextBoxDetails as TextBox;

            if (TextBoxDetails != null)
            {

                string _CurrentValue = BehaveTextbox.Text;
                var _CareIndex = BehaveTextbox.CaretIndex;

                if (_CareIndex > 0)
                {
                    string _Backspace = _CurrentValue.Remove(_CareIndex - 1, 1);
                    BehaveTextbox.Text = _Backspace;
                    BehaveTextbox.Focus();
                    BehaveTextbox.CaretIndex = _CareIndex - 1;
                }
            }
        }

        private void txt_result_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            TextBoxDetails = (Control)sender;
        }
    }
```